# Delphi Service Application: Como instalar o serviço passando parâmetros que serão lidos via código ao executar?

Tags: delphi, parâmetros, application-service

Eu criei uma aplicação simples de serviço pelo Delphi.

Eu preciso que no momento de instalar o serviço no windows, eu passe alguns parâmetros que serão lidos e utilizados no momento que o serviço iniciar:

> Exemplo: myServiceApp /install **-arg1 -arg2**

Tentei dessa forma porém não funciona. Além disso tentei "forcar" nos parâmetros de inicialização pela propriedade do serviço instalado, mas não consegui obter o valor desse parâmetro via ParamStr().

Como passar esses parâmetros iniciais e como ler o valor pelo Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

[image: Parâmetros na inicialização do serviço]

1. Adicionei os parâmetros na propriedade do serviço.
2. No evento OnStart() no Delphi, consigo pegar os valores desses parâmetros através do Param[index]:

[image: Evento OnStart do Serviço em Delphi]

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu. Mas não podias criar um INI file com os parâmetros?

Comment: Sim, era uma outra opção. Problema agora é que ao instalar no servidor do cliente (Windows Server 2012) o serviço não inicia (start).

Comment: algum erro logo no arranque... é  tratar tudo com try catch e por no event viewer.